# How to force request function terminate in node.js if the response is not returned after a long time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, terminate

My program has to deal with a huge amount of requests, some of them sometimes cannot get the returned callback (because of the server I send requests to). I'm wondering if there is any way for me to force the request terminate after a certain amount of time (for example 5s)?

```
request(item.url, function (error, response, html) {})
```

I really appreciate for any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747632/node-js-how-to-stop-an-already-started-http-request) help you at all? It seems like you could just get the return value of the `request()` call and then call `setTimeout(requestReturnValue.abort.bind(requestReturnValue), 5000)` to abort the request after five seconds. I don't know Node.js, though, so I might be wrong.

Comment: Can I just write setTimeout(requestReturnValue.abort(), 5000) ? @NobleMushtak

Comment: You could try it. I don't know how Node.js works, so it could work. However, usually, I use `Function.prototype.bind` when passing methods into `setTimeout()` so the value of `this` within the method is not lost.

Comment: @NobleMushtak thank you very much. I will try it now :)

Comment: @NobleMushtak I just tried, but it works but in other way. I have, say 100 requests, when I use "setTimeout(requestReturnValue.abort.bind(requestReturnValue), 5000)", it doesn't abort each request, it abort all 100 requests after 5s. (I use setInterval to trigger 100 requests by the time interval of, for example, 10ms)

Comment: Wait, so does `setTimeout(requestReturnValue.abort, 5000)` without the `.bind()` work? If it does, then you've found your answer, right?

Comment: @NobleMushtak no, I tried, and it didn't work. I really don't know why

Comment: This is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/mmzee174/ @NobleMushtak

Comment: I wish I could help you more, but I don't know that much about Node.js, so I don't know how to help you. I wish you good luck, though!

Comment: @NobleMushtak anyway, your help is really appreciated. I will try to figure it out myself based on what you told me :). Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The `request` module has a [`timeout` option](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback):

> `timeout` - Integer containing the number of milliseconds to wait for a server to send response headers (and start the response body) before aborting the request. Note that if the underlying TCP connection cannot be established, the OS-wide TCP connection timeout will overrule the `timeout` option ([the default in Linux can be anywhere from 20-120 seconds](http://www.sekuda.com/overriding_the_default_linux_kernel_20_second_tcp_socket_connect_timeout)).

Comment: thank you. However, there is one thing that I'm still confused about.
if the server sends response headers (and start the response body) before the timeout ends, is the request still aborted ?

Comment: As the documentation says, it will abort the request before headers are received. Once you see the `response` event though, you can start your own timer if you want to limit how long it takes for the response to complete.

Comment: This is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/oe6freko/.
When dealing with a huge amount of requests, this example sometimes print out `req.abort is excuted AFTER response is returned in callback function`. Can you help me out with this case? @mscdex

Comment: if the response is returned in the callback function, I don't want req.abort to be executed (callback function in `req.setTimeout(myTimeout, callback)` shouldn't be called)